# How to handle TCP keepalive in application

Tags: sockets, tcp, vxworks

I have a TCP application running on VxWorks. I have SO_KEEPALIVE option set for my TCP connections. My application keep track of all TCP connection and put it into a link list.

If client is idle for long time, we see that connection is closing down. Connection is not listed in netstat output.

As the connection is closed by TCP stack, resources allocated for that connection are not cleaned up. Can you please help me figure out how does application get notified if connection is closed due to keep-alive's failures.

Answer (score 3):

TCP keepalive is intended primarily to prevent network routers from shutting the TCP connection down during long periods of inactivity, not to prevent your OS or application from shutting down the connection when it deems appropriate.

In most TCP/IP implementations, you can determine if a connection has been closed by attempting to read from it.

Comment: Thanks, yes read/write from close connection can help. I want to understand if this is best way to do it or there are other approaches as well.

Comment: It might depend on exactly which TCP/IP implementation you are using, but in most implementations that I've seen, a read (not a write) is the best way to do it.

Comment: How can a router shutdown a connection between 2 peers ?

Comment: @PhilipStuyck By sending FINs or RSTs.

Answer (score 1):

From this reference : http://tldp.org/HOWTO/TCP-Keepalive-HOWTO/overview.html

I quote :

> This procedure is useful because if the other peers lose their connection (for example by rebooting) you will notice that the connection is broken, even if you don't have traffic on it. If the keepalive probes are not replied to by your peer, you can assert that the connection cannot be considered valid and then take the correct action.

If you have a server for instance and a lot of clients can connect to it, without sending regularly, you might end up in a situation with clients that are no longer there. A client may have rebooted and this goes undetected because a FIN is never sent in that case.

For cases like this the keepalive exists.

From TCP point of view there is nothing special with a keep alive. And hence if the peer fails to ack a keepalive, you will receive 0 bytes on your socket and you'll have to close your end of the socket. Which is the only corrective action you can do at that moment.

Answer (score 0):

> As the connection is closed by TCP stack, resources allocated for that connection are not cleaned up.

Only if you never use the connection again.

> If client is idle for long time, we see that connection is closing down. Connection is not listed in netstat output.

Make up your mind. Either you see it or you don't. What you will see is the port in CLOSE_WAIT in netstat.

> Can you please help me figure out how does application get notified if connection is closed due to keep-alive's failures.

Next time you use the connection for read or write you will get an ECONNRESET.